# A small grammatical question, I’m confused!

Tags: present-tense, simple-past

Which sentence is correct?
“Why did you go and told mom about us?”
“Why did you go and tell mom about us?”

I know that after “did”, the verb has to come as “simple form”, but when the sentence is long and follows with “and”, what happens to the second verb (after and) ?
Does it have to come as “past tense” or “present tense”?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it: **Why did you tell mom about us?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be "go and tell ..." regardless of the preceding "Why did you ... ?". I can't think of a case in which "go and told ..." would be correct or idiomatic.

"My brother went and told my mother what I'd done" would be the past tense construction.